# String with multiple whitespaces on javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add whitespaces between two strings and put it as one of the series name of highcharts graph. However, Javascript automatically ignores excessive whitespaces. Is there any way I can put as many whitespaces as I want to a string?

Here is my sample code:

```
var i = 's';
i = i.concat(Array(12).join(' '),'ss');
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: i,
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Also, here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/NJ6Eq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's the HTML that ignores the excessive whitespace. To prevent this, you need to use non-breaking spaces:

```
i = i.concat(Array(12).join('&nbsp;'),'ss');
```

Also, you now need to tell highcharts that your chart uses HTML labels rather than text:

```
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    borderWidth: 0,
    useHTML: true
},
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NJ6Eq/3/

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
 \u00a0
```

to add multiple spaces

edit-
heres the result - http://jsfiddle.net/NJ6Eq/4/

Comment: &nbsp; is html-related and the highcharts code doesnt allow html by default [look at Borre comment to see how change that]

Comment: Came only aware of this because it was a close-candidate. Didnt vote for closing this answer, now everybody hopefully can see why not.

Comment: This works well. I guess the highcharts use pre tags around the title so &nbsp; doesn't work..

Comment: Thanks this works well when exporting (I export to SVG and then to other formats)

Answer (score 0):

In some situations I found that I can't use anything but this special white space that JavaScript or html does not know it's a white-space. ->" "

**UPDATE**

Looks like stack over flow replaces it with a regular space so here is the ASCII code for it

Dec 160 Hex A0 Oct 240